# Ideas on source to learn the ins and outs of all Web Operations?

Tags: web-access

Since beginning to learn Mathematica a few months ago, I have been amazed by its capabilities. I have recently come across basic web operations such as URLFetch and I am interested in learning more. Would anyone happen to know a good source to learn the ins and outs of Mathematica web operations? Eventually I would like to get to the point where I can easily import and export any kind of data such as downloading files from a specific URL, input information for requested by URL, logging into accounts such my email and more. Please Advise.

Thank you!

Comment: You might consider reading up on APIs; I've found on many separate occasions that *Mathematica*'s abilities are vastly augmented by being able to use these with `URL*[]` functions.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your input!